# Как быстро и красиво отрисовать множество динамических кругов?

Tags: opengl, шейдеры, glsl

Использую язык Rust и библиотеку Glium. Хочу отобразить на экране некоторое количество кругов, например, 512. Но никак не могу определиться, как мне это лучше сделать. Есть вариант создавать круги из треугольников, также можно рисовать их фрагментным шейдером, т.е. считать расстояние от центра каждого круга до каждой точки на экране и если оно меньше радиуса, то закрашивать его в нужный цвет.

Для ясности вот пример того, как я рисую один круг:

```
vec2 point = vec2(200.0f, 200.0f);
float dist = distance(point, gl_FragCoord.xy);

if (dist < 200)
    gl_FragColor = vec4(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
```

И вот вопрос, какой способ будет работать быстрее в большинстве случаев?
Для полного понимания всей картины покажу то, что мне хочется видеть в результате:

[image: симулятор гравитации]

И да, это симулятор гравитации. Хотелось бы уточнить, что радиус и цвет кругов будут постоянно изменяться.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам придется попробовать несколько разных вариантов и выбрать тот который вам устроит по скорости и качеству отрисовки:

- **высчитывание** кругов **в шейдере** отметаем сразу, т.к. будет несчадно тормозить
- рисовать **спрайтами** (2 треугольника + текстурка). Для разных размеров можно масштабировать и подменять текстуру при переходе некоторых порогов (например 1-3 пикс, 4-8 пикс, 9 - 15 пикс и т.д.). Текстура может быть одноканальной и ипсользоваться только для прозрачности, а цвет передаваться отдельно.
- рисовать **геометрией** - т.е. создать 1 круг из полигонов и отрисовывать его кучу раз меняя цвет, положение и размер
- для оптимизации можно сделать буфер с N кругами (задав каждому атрибут номера), спрайтами или геометрией, не важно, и **рисовать круги пачками** по N штук передавая N комплектов цвета, положений и размеров применяя в шейдере соответственно номерам вершин.

P.S. Посмотрите в сторону туториалов по отрисовке частиц - там могут быть и другие способы.

Comment: Все же, я думаю, что вариант со спрайтами не подойдет, так как мне бы хотелось менять цвет кругов(ярко зеленый - самый маленький круг, ярко красный - самый большой). Извиняюсь, что не уточнил это сразу.

Comment: На самом деле, я просто переношу свой C++ проект, где все было именно так и мне бы не хотелось изменять внешний вид программы. Там я рисовал круги треугольниками и для того, чтобы круги смотрелись действительно кругами(а не шестиугольниками), я выставлял количество точек, из которых состояла граница круга, равным его радиусу в пикселях. Поэтому, их получалось достаточно много. В варианте с шейдером круги будут круглыми на столько, на сколько это возможно.

Comment: Менять цвет спрайтов легко - просто используйте одноканальную текстуру - у нее в glsl все каналы будут одинаковыми, в итоге что-то типа `vec4 resultColor = vec4(color, texture(uTex, uv).r)`. Идеальными круги никогда не будут, хотя бы из-за пикселей на мониторе, так что не гонитесь за идеалом и сделайте так, как будет достаточно ровно.

Answer (score 1):

Очевидно, вариант с рисованием круга путем подсчета расстояния до каждого круга в пиксельном шейдере будет нещадно тормозить, так как придется вычислять расстояния *количество_пикселей* x *количество_кругов* раз. Проще всего их рисовать в виде обычного спрайта из двух треугольников с текстурой круга.

Comment: Я забыл уточнить, что радиус кругов постоянно  изменяется. Не думаю, что вариант со спрайтами подойдёт для этого.

Comment: Так и менять размер спрайтов как надо - переслать в видеокарту информацию о паре новых треугольников не долго же, особенно если разом все это делать.

Comment: @ozkriff, пожалуйста, прочитайте мои комментарии к следующему ответу. Там я немного уточняю ситуацию.